# Execute when both(!) events fire .on('end')

Tags: node.js, eventemitter, node.js-stream

I have a node app that reads two files as streams. I use `event.on('end')` to then work with the results. The problem is I don't really know how I can wait for BOTH events to trigger 'end'.

What I have now is:

```
    reader1.on('end', function(){
        reader2.on('end',function(){ 
          doSomething();
        });
    });
```

With small files this works, but if one of the files is very large the app aborts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your execution logic is somewhat flawed. You ought to do something like this instead

```
var checklist = [];
 // checklist will contain sort of a counter
function reader_end(){
    if(checklist.length == 2 )
     // doSomething only if both have been added to the checklist
        doSomething();
}
reader1.on('end', function() {
    checklist.push('reader1');
    // increment the counter
    reader_end();
});
reader2.on('end', function() {
    checklist.push('reader2');
    reader_end();
});
```

Although there are libraries to better handle this sort of stuff, like Async and Promises.

---

With [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) you'll need to use [`compose`](https://github.com/caolan/async#compose)

```
var r12_done = async.compose(reader1.on, reader2.on);
r12_done('end', function(){
    doSomething();
});
```

**Edit**: I just noticed that since probably `reader1.on` is a [Stream 'end' event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) which doesn't have the standard callback argument signature of `(err, results)`, this probably won't work. In that case you should just go with Promise.

---

With [Promise](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) you'll need to first [Promisify](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyfunction-nodefunction--dynamic-receiver---function) and then [join](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisejoinpromisethenablevalue-promises-function-handler---promise)

```
var reader1Promise = Promise.promisify(reader1.on)('end');
var reader2Promise = Promise.promisify(reader2.on)('end');

var reader12Promise = Promise.join(reader1Promise, reader1Promise);

reader12Promise.then(function(){
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: That works, thank you @laggingreflex ! However, async with .on('end')  didn't work for me. I am curious about how async.parallel might work for this.